# Using a regex to test a string

Tags: regex, groovy

I am testing responses from a server method...

They are off the form:

`__access=e332baa1-8237-4205-a9be-76b9ecaaace6; Expires=Fri, 15-Dec-2023 17:53:25 GMT; Path=/lexter/shop/pired; Secure`

I just want to check that the String between the `=` after Path and before the `;` is equal to

```
/lexter/shop/pired
```

So a regex to check that such a string is contained, I could do:

```
assert myString =~ 'Path=([/a-z]*);'
```

But what I'd like to do, pull out the part between the = and ; and compare for an exact match to `/lexter/shop/pired`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not simply try to find `Path=/lexter/shop/pired;` in the string? If there's a match, that part you're looking for equals to `/lexter/shop/pired`, and otherwise, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, replace

```
assert myString =~ 'Path=([/a-z]*);'
```

With

```
assert myString =~ 'Path=(/lexter/shop/pired);'
```

For fun you can keep the `(` and `)` though they are not needed

Comment: I'd recommend encapsulating the regex in forward slashes rather than quotes: myString =~ /Path=(/lexter/shop/pired);/